# How to delete a product programmatically in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I've been checking different threads about how to delete a product programmatically in Magento 2. The different solutions proposed are:

- Using the Registry to set after that the securedArea parameter
- Overriding type RemoveAction arguments in our di.xml
- Using Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface

This solutions are discussed in this thread: [Delete operation is forbidden for current area](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65087/delete-operation-is-forbidden-for-current-area)

The only one that works fine is setting the isSecuredArea parameter to true. But in Magento 2.4, the use of the class Magento\Framework\Registry is deprecated.

What is the correct way to delete a product programmatically in Magento 2.4?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this question? I'm in the same predicament.

Comment: Hi @gabtzi. Sadly, I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;

class DeleteProduct
{
    /** @var ProductRepository */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * DeleteProduct constructor.
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $productId
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws StateException
     */
    public function delete(int $productId): void
    {
        $this->productRepository->deleteById($productId);
    }
}
```

run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

so that dependency injection knows about the new class and its dependencies

http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/magento-new-class-instance.php

if you are using command object, can you inject state in your command object?

```
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

/** @var State */
private $appState;

public function __construct(
        State $state,
) {
    $this->appState = $state;
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void
{
    $this->appState->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I try to execute it, I get the error «Delete operation is forbidden for current area». Setting the area code doesn't work either (I've tried setting the area to 'frontend' and 'adminhtml'.

Answer (score 1):

**This work for me,**

```
 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
        // Using Sku
        $this->_productRepository->deleteById('24-MB01');

        // Using Product Id
        $productColl = $this->_productRepository->getById(10);
        $this->_productRepository->delete($productColl);
    }
```

**Hope it works for you**

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.

```
$productID = 999;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->load($productID)->delete();
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Hi @sarvesh, thanks for your answer, but using the object manager is not the recommended good practice by magento. I would like to do this with DI, any idea?

Comment: okay, will update to you.